# add timeframe in tradingview

Tags: reactjs, charts, tradingview-api

I'm integrating tradinview chart in React.js and I want to add multiple timeframes in the chart, I've attached a screenshot of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific in what help you require here please. Is it CSS, JavaScript or both?

Comment: hey, @KieranFoot I need a javascript configuration for timeframe which looks like the screenshot.